# Insert list register with onchange (Odoo)

Tags: odoo, onchange, odoo-8

```
class base(models.Model):
    _name = 'base'

    name = fields.Char("Name")
    c_id = fields.Many2one('base.ch')

class base_ch(models.Model):
    _name = 'base.ch'

    name = fields.Char("Name")
    q_ids = fields.One2many("base.q","c_id")


class base_q(models.Model):
    _name = "base.q"

    name = fields.Char("Name")
    c_id = fields.Many2one('base.ch',"Basec")


class base_h(models.Model):
    _name = "base.h"

    name = fields.Char("Name")
    select = fields.Selection([('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B')], "select")
    desc = fields.Char("Desc")
```

I have these classes and I want to add in the base class a field of the base_h class in  tree view format.
I need to do an onchange function in the base class that when choosing c_id modify the name field of the added field of the base_h class with the records of c_id.q_ids

I tried:

```
@api.onchange('ch_id')
def onchange_ch(self):
    if self.ch_id.q_ids:
        self.one2manyfield.name = [(6, 0, self.ch_id.q_ids)]
        #also with-> self.one2manyfield = [(6, 0, self.ch_id.q_ids)]
```

But it does not work

Comment: Create on base a One2many field to base_h and onchange I have tried two things.     1.- (self.one2many_field = self.c_id.q_ids)   and  2.- (self.one2many_field = [(6,0, self.c_id.q_ids)] )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function that works

```
@api.onchange('ch_id')
def onch_ch(self):
    valors = []
    for r in self.ch_id.q_ids:
        register = {'name': r.name}
        valors.append(register)
    self.one2manyfield = valors
```

Answer (score 0):

*(6, 0, [IDs])* will take list of ids.

Try with following code.

```
@api.onchange('ch_id')
def onchange_ch(self):
    if self.ch_id and self.ch_id.q_ids:
        one2manyfield = [(6, 0, self.cht_id.q_ids.ids)]
```